# Problem deploying Cocoon within Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, apache-cocoon

I am trying to deploy cocoon (2.1.11) in Tomcat (7.0.12) (I know that I can run cocoon standalone and have done that successfully, but I am trying to better understand the whole web application environment) I have built the cocoon.war file, copied it to the tomcat/webapps directory and started tomcat.

All the web pages I have consulted explicitly say that this is all that is required.
I can see that the .war file is unpacked into a cocoon subdirectory, and cocoon shows up as one of the applications. But when I browse to this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/cocoon
```

I get this Java traceback:

```
org.apache.cocoon.ResourceNotFoundException: No pipeline matched request: index.html
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:149)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:69)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:93)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:235)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:177)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.process(TreeProcessor.java:254)
    at org.apache.cocoon.Cocoon.process(Cocoon.java:699)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servlet.CocoonServlet.service(CocoonServlet.java:1154)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Can anyone help me to understand why?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is years old, 
I just used http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1178 cocoon-soap.war on a tomcat 7.0.29 deployment and needed to modify sitemap.xmap to include a

```
 <map:match pattern="index.html">
```

as well as the following:

```
<map:match pattern=""> 
 <map:generate src="index.html"/>
 <map:serialize/>
</map:match>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs because you do not have your sitemap setup correctly.  do you have a generic .html pipeline declared in your sitemap.